# Where is the rest of Rabbi Shmuel Belkin's manuscript of The Midrash of Philo?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, history, torah-study, jewish-books

I am currently researching Philo of Alexandria, also known as Philon (פילון) or Yedidyah HaKohen of Alexandria.

There is a book that was prepared in manuscript by Rabbi Shmuel (Samuel) Belkin, z”l, the past Rosh Yeshiva of Yeshiva University called *The Midrash of Philo* ([מדרשי פילון](https://www.sefaria.org/The_Midrash_of_Philo?lang=he)) which was intended to be six volumes. In Rabbi Belkin’s introduction to volume one, he goes into detail about the content of each volume.

Rabbi Belkin passed away before the book was published but Rav Avraham Yosef Hirschprung and Rabbi Elazar Hurvitz took it upon themselves to actually bring the manuscript to publication.

Volume one was successfully published by Yeshiva University in 1989 (5749). But the remaining five volumes never saw the light of day.

Does anyone know where this manuscript went or how to contact Rabbis Hirschprung and Hurvitz?

I would like to assist in finally getting the remaining five volumes published. It is long overdue.

Comment: Did you try contacting YU (either the publishing house or the library)? They are more likely to know than us.

Comment: @DoubleAA YU has essentially been shut down since Covid broke out. All their non-student services are not responding. But the community here is large. Someone out there may know how to make the connections. I don’t know if you are familiar with Rabbi Belkin or this sefer, but it’s an important one. This really needs to happen. It sounds like it was just a money issue. That’s not acceptable.

Comment: @DoubleAA To clarify, yes, I’ve tried and continue to pursue this. I only acquired מדרשי פילון volume 1 last February. It’s incredible. Not a surprise coming from a musmach from the Chofetz Chaim. Rabbi Belkin started out at the yeshiva in Radun.

Comment: I am a student of Dr. Hurvitz (that is the correct spelling) and he has complained many times about how Dr Belkins work on Philo never was published. I can give you his contact, but how should we connect? I’m not sure how to do it without making everyone’s emails public.

Comment: @moses Just to give you an update, I have tried again to contact Dr. Hurvitz directly through his email at the university. Since I am not an alumnus of YU, he may not take particular regard or think it is simply spam. Since you are a current student of his, if you could give him a 'heads-up' to be on the lookout for a Subject line of "Sefer Midrashei Philon" and possibly mention that you know of me via Mi Yodeya, perhaps this will help to get the remaining 5 volumes of this important sefer finally published.

Comment: I spoke with him last night (before I saw this post). He said that there are 9 unprinted volumes that he has. He also said that what he really needs is someone who can translate Armenian into Hebrew. Armenian to English will not do. 
Also, I’m not sure he ever checks his email (he’s literally from a different era).

Comment: @moses Interesting request about the Armenian. I'm guessing, based on my own research at this point, that he is looking at the (5th century) Armenian translations of the original Greek manuscripts of the Philon dealing with his questions and answers on Sefer Bereshit and Sefer Shemot. Unlike him, I am not from a "different era" and have ideas how to pursue his objective. Hopefully, he will either write or call me. I gave him my contact information in my email to him. Perhaps one of his children could retrieve it for him.

Comment: @moses If Dr. Hurvitz has 9 volumes, that means he has expanded whatever Dr. Belkin's original material was. Perhaps he left additional material and explanations, or perhaps Dr. Hurvitz is intending to included the other project that was mentioned at the end of the original introduction. Either way, let him know that there is someone very interested in helping him to make it happen.

Comment: @mose One last detail worth passing along to Dr. Hurvitz, if he isn't already aware of this. I just discovered over the weekend the Bialik Institute in Israel is working on a new complete translation from the original language of all the writings of Philon. They currently have 5 volumes published with several people working on it. I'm in the process of obtaining a copy.

Comment: @Moses Please ping me back that you received this message. I am working on making contact with the individuals in Israel who are currently working on this project. Several of their original contributors have also passed away over the decades. It seems to me that this would be an excellent opportunity for some type of collaboration to complete a common objective and also to complete the work of and honor Rabbi/Dr. Belkin, A"H. Please extend my regards to Dr. Hurvitz & tell him that if he wants a reference for me, he can contact a prior alumnus he might know, Rabbi Jesse Shore.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. iyh I will call him and relay your message.

Comment: @moses Thanks for pinging back. I just removed the public comment with my number.

Comment: @moses B"H, I actually spoke with Dr. Hurvitz today concerning the balance of the manuscript. It's not 9 volumes, it's still the original 6. He is interested in my offer to assist and asked that I send him a letter detailing what I propose. He said he needs permission from the University to take the time off  to finish the final edits. Thanks for your interest. B'ezrat HaShem, this very important sefer will come to see the light of day after so many years.

Comment: In the meantime, many of his writings can be found [here](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com) for free.